# *** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: with shopify App

Tags: python, django

this is my models.py

```
class ShopifyUserProfile(models.Model):
    shop_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile) 
    ....
```

i am tring to save its object in views.py

```
  shop=shopify.Shop.current()
  saved = ShopifyUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(shop_user.user = shop.attributes['shop_owner'], shop_name = shop.attributes['name'],.... etc )
```

When i am tring to save it pops up an error

```
*** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'somevalue'
```

i tried :

```
temp = shop.attributes['shop_owner']
temp=temp.strip()
temp=str(temp)
```

still getting same error .

UPDATE : it might be that shop_user is a foreign key and we can explicitly assign .

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
```

For that i even tried :

```
ShopifyUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(shop_user.user = temp)
```

It pops up the new error :

```
*** SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (<stdin>, line 1)
```

Where I am going wrong ??

UPDATE (Corrected as per the ans i.e passing the object now ) but still getting the same error :

```
subs, stat = Subscription.objects.get_or_create(validity=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=30))
user, stat = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=shop.attributes['shop_owner'],subscription=subs)

saved = ShopifyUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(shop_user =user ,shop_name = shop.attributes['name'],...
```

ERROR :

```
ipdb> user, stat = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=shop.attributes['shop_owner'],subscription=subs)
*** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jofin Joseph'
```

Comment: did you really pass `'somevalue'` to `int()`? if so, you can't turn that literal into an int (not without packing + ordinals)

Comment: Is `somevalue` actually *somevalue* or you just put that in the question? This is an `int` invalid conversion.

Comment: that value contains a string value .. say my name . the sense of passing it through int() . was not digestive for me .

Comment: Is your `get_or_create` correct? It should be impossible to use `shop_user.user` as a key value.

Comment: wessie by using this .objects.get_or_create() , its not my function .

Comment: Could you write your code exactly? Just change _sensitive_ information, but the full code where the problem is located, without *...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require to pass either an `User` object or an `User.id` value to your `ShopifyUserProfile.get_or_create` call.

In your case you are passing in a string that is then passed to `int` since Django expects an integer. You either have to create an `User` object for it, or retrieve the relevant `User` object from the database beforehand.

Your call should look like this if you have the `User` object:

```
ShopifyUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user_object, ...)
```